# Тестовый сервер для сайта

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Всем привет.
Нужно использовать "временный" сервер для одного сайта и для одного пользователя.
Суть - нужно поднять сервер на ноутбуке для личного (это пока) пользования одного сайта.
Можно ли использовать встроенный сервер VS? Если да то где начать копать или курить мануалы.

P.S.
Сорян. Также остаюсь нубом в программировании, ибо оставлял эту тему.
Также сорян за заголовок. Просто ничего не лезло в голову.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы запустить локальный сервер, можно в командной строке зайти в папку со своей сборкой и выполнить dotnet MyProject.dll , только не забудь в конфигурационных файлах (appsettings.json, launchSettings.json) указать адрес сети, из которой этот сервер должен быть доступен. Если останется localhost, то из сети он виден не будет.

А если необходимость будет повторяться, то советую один раз разобраться с docker, чтобы уметь поднимать любые сервера за считанные секунды.

Answer (score 1):

VS при старте отладки веб приложений запускает IIS Express (в случае с ASP.NET), который можно запускать и без VS (через ту же CMD), в случае с .NET.Core можно использовать Kestrel и ставить приложение как сервис винды, либо запускать .exe. Вообщем советую покурить в эти стороны.

Comment: Огромное спасибо.